# what are the widest 700c available(with kevlar)?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, wheels, hybrid-bike

Is it possible to put wider tires on the wheels I have? 
(original wheels on a Giant hybrid...GX-02 622 x 19)

I have 700c x 38mm(Schwinn kevlar tires now). I would like something similar...TIA

Comment: Product info requests that are open ended (what are the widest tires...) are discouraged as there's no canonical answer. There may always be a wider tire that comes out. You should rephrase as "Can I get wider tires than 38mm for the 622x19 rims that I have?" And it may still be closed as a duplicate question.

Comment: Given that 700C is the same as 29" (in the MTB world) there are some really rather wide tyres in your size

Comment: Doubtless there's something 3-4" wide in the 29" fatbike line, but good luck getting that in your forks/frame!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is generally possible to install wider tires that those which came with a bike.

The limiting factors are the clearance available in the forks and frame. The chainstays/bottom bracket area is usually the most constricted area.

The rims will also have a maximum size of tire they can support, but the frame clearance is likely a more limiting factor.

If you have 38mm tires now, you can probably step up to 40 or 42mm.